# Whats the difference between 'chr(32)' and 'chr(0)'?

Tags: python

Why even we have to have two characters like space ?
and why space is `chr(32)` and not `chr(0)` ?

also `chr(160)` is A half space ??
[image]

Comment: Note that there are [a ton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) of different whitespace characters if you think outside ASCII (and you should). They all serve different purposes.

Answer (score 9):

`chr(0)` isn't actually a space, it's a NULL character. [`chr(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#chr) returns the [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the number n.

When you `print(chr(0))`, it just prints the representation of the NULL character, which is nothing.

Observe:

```
>>> print('hi'+chr(0)+'hello')
hihello
>>> print('hi'+chr(32)+'hello')
hi hello
```

Note that NULL is not None, nor is it even an empty string:

```
>>> chr(0) is None
False
>>> chr(0) == ''
False
```

It is literally nothing.

Comment: actually, that's not the output python gives. `print('hi'+chr(0)+'hello')` actually prints `hi hello` with the space (tested in both python 2.7. and 3.6.1.).

While chr(0) is definitely the null character, it seems python does print it as a space for some reason.

Comment: @Zinki No, Python prints **a null character**. How that is rendered depends on your console, environment, and font.

Comment: @MehdiHoseini Which python interactive shell are you using, also what version of python?

Comment: @TerryA not OP, but I tested it in windows command line (both 2.7 and 3.6), IDLE for 2.7. and eclipse with both, all of them print chr(0) as a space, which I find quite strange.

Comment: @Zinki Very strange for windows to do that... I'm a Mac OS X user and Terminal prints Nothing. Guess poke response deals for OP too

Comment: @TerryA  IDLE python 3.5

Answer (score 5):

`chr(0)` is `NULL` character, which is very significant and `chr(32)` is `' '`. The point of `NULL` character is to terminate strings for example. So what you see like `x = "abcd"` is actaully `x = "abcd\00"`, where of course `\00` is the same as `chr(0)`. Without null character you would not be able to determine the end of strings, because what might happen is that you read string byte by byte, but right after `"abcd"`there is something else stored in memory, `y = "efgh"` for example. If there would be no null char at the end of `x`, calling `print(x)` would print `'abcdefgh'` and maybe even more garbage that is not `x` because the computer would not know when to stop.

Answer (score 2):

If not mistaken [chr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr)(int) converts the int (Decimal value) to the character in the [ascii code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)...

char(0) is Null
char(32) is space

Answer (score 1):

Actually [chr(n)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#chr) returns not the ASCII code but the Unicode codepoint for n. The first elements Unicode happen to be the same as the ASCII ones.

Try it yourself: `chr(15265)` returns '㮡' in Python 3.6

Comment: In Python 2, `chr()` operates only on ASCII though.